# Completely removing PhpMyAdmin from Debian 7

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

For some reason, my PhpMyAdmin on a new-ish server was giving me the 500 internal error.

I can completely remove PMA since it's not being used for anything currently, but I'd like to set up my database on it.

I done

```
apt-get remove phpmyadmin
apt-get --purge phpmyadmin
service apache2 restart
```

I also remove the include line from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Then the `etc/phpmyadmin` file has been removed, however `http://198.245.62.75/phpmyadmin/` still asks for a username/password and re-installing gives me the same issues.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this please?

Comment: Did you try looking at the apache error log for the actual reason for the 500 error?

Comment: It turns out htpasswd.setup wasn't correct, so I reinstalled and it was still there. I just generated a new .htpasswd file and copied/pasted the data in to that file - tada, works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin  
sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin
```

And clear you cache ;)